# Neworking getting Disabled

Tags: fedora, networking

I am using Fedora 13 and its working great. The only problem which I am facing is that the networking gets automatically disabled if I put my system on the "SUSPEND" mode for > 30mins. I am unable to enable it even after right clicking. Then I have to restart my system, to get the internet working. Can anyone show me how to rectify this!

Comment: So stop suspending it and use hibernate or shut down? Fedora 13 is just out recently and still ironing the kinks out, we sleep in the bed we lay and picking a distribution is no different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been having the same issue with Fedora 13. It has been hit or miss when network does not work after suspend for me. Here is what I run in a terminal to restart the network connection.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/NetworkManager restart
```

Update:
this is a work around from [this post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1395382&postcount=17) at Fedora forums

In a text editor open

```
sudo vi  /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager
```

on each line that says (I had two entries)

> dbus_send --system      \

add

> --print-reply

so it looks like this:

> dbus_send --system --print-reply \

After the edit I tried suspend everything resumed fine, but; I have not given it any heavy testing.

Comment: I've been having the same issues and this is how I've been getting around it.  I saved it as a script so I can quickly run it from gnome-do after I wake back up.